# Prove that the formula $Af=(f(2^{-k})_{k\geq1}$ defines a bounded linear operator.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I am having difficulty with exactly how to go about this question. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Let $Y=C[0,1]$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions equipped with the supremum norm $||.||_{\infty}$ and $Z=l_{\infty}$ be the space of bounded sequences of real numbers equipped with its usual norm $||(c_k)_{k\geq 1}||_{\infty}= \sup_{k\geq 1}|c_k|$.

Prove that the formula $Af=(f(2^{-k}))_{k\geq1}$ defines a linear bounded operator $A:Y\rightarrow Z$. Find ||A||.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  Linear or bounded?

Comment: Bounded - I think that it is relatively straight forward to show it is linear

Comment: What's causing you trouble showing that it's bounded?

Comment: So I ideally want to show that $sup_{k\geq1}|f(2^{-k})| \leq C sup\{f(t):t \in [0,1] \}$. However, I am struggling to find a C to demonstrate this is the case. Therefore, I am wondering if I am attacking this problem from the wrong angle.

Comment: Well, $2^{-k}\in[0,1]$, so...  (Also, remember that it should be $|f(t)|$ on the right hand side, not $f(t)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|f(2^{-k})| \le ||f||_{\infty}$ for all $k$, we get

$||A(f)||_{\infty}=\sup_{k\geq 1}|f(2^{-k})| \le ||f||_{\infty}$.

This shows that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: I am not sure why the first line of the statement is true.

Comment: We have $|f(2^{-k})| \le \max \{|f(t)|:t \in [0,1]\}= ||f||_{\infty}$

Comment: Okay, so what would the norm of this linear operator be? Would it just be 1?